# I am trying to plot a geojson circle with a point in it... But it does not merge in the geometries part in it

Tags: python, geojson

```
geo_json = [ 
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [lon, lat] 
        },
        "properties": {}
    }
]
```

I want the circle coordinates to come in the same format as the above code..

```
import geojson
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import Point

center = Point(lat,long) 
circle = center.buffer(0.3)  
poly = geojson.dumps(shapely.geometry.mapping(circle))

feature_col = FeatureCollection([geo_json,circle])
print(poly)
```

But I can't possibly do that for circle polygon. Is there any other method where we can do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
import shapely, geojson
lat = long = 0
center = shapely.geometry.Point([lat, long])
poly = list(center.buffer(0.3).exterior.coords)
json_points = [geojson.Feature(geometry=shapely.geometry.Point(p)) for p in poly_points]
json_points = geojson.FeatureCollection(json_points)
```

Since both shapely.geometry.Point and geojson.Point exist, I would avoid importing either as simply "Point", even if this entails some cumbersome calls.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering ... Actually I can plot the circle coordinates..but I cant get the json in the format as seen in..{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates":   /*circle coordinates*/
        },
        "properties": {}
    }


So could you please let me know any way to get the circle coordinates in the above format ?

Comment: I found another solution !! But the above one works too Thank you so much @non87 !!